# registering .NET assemblies

Tags: .net, com-interop

Visual Studio produces an XML file and a PDB file when I produce a DLL.

- What are these files used for?
- Do they have to be copied to the System32 folder (assuming that the DLL is stored in the System32 folder) when registering the DLL?

I am using REGASM for COM interoperability.

Comment: You likely shouldn't be copying your dll to System32

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The xml file contains the xml style comments that decorate the code.

for example:

```
///<summary>
///This method adds two integers
///</summary>
public int Add(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}
```

The pdb file is a [program database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_database) contains the symbols needed to debug the code.

Neither are required for running the program normally.

Answer (score 0):

PDB contains debug-infos, the file is needed only when you debug your program. When you compile in release-mode no PDB is created. Regarding the XML, what VS version do you use and what solution type do you compile in?